# Multisearch pg_search with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg-search

I have a question about multi field search using `pg_search` gem. What I want to do is make a query in multiples fields, so I have the following code in my `Client` model:

```
  pg_search_scope :search,
    :against => [:name, :email],
    :using => [:trigram, :tsearch],
    :ignoring => :accents
```

For testing I have:

### Client 1

name: "Anna"

email: "mycompany@foo.com"

Then I searched with `Client.search("anna")` and no results are returned. Or
`Client.search("nna")` also no results found.

Any suggestion here ?

Thanks in advance.

### Update 1

I set the `threshold` manually and it works:

```
  pg_search_scope :search,
    :against => [:name, :email],
    using: {
            tsearch: {},
            trigram:    {threshold:  0.1}
           }
```

Comment: Have you set:  "include PgSearch" on the top of your model?

Comment: @AlessandroCaetano yes.